# "Software updates available," but I can't install them

Tags: updates, notification

This message is shown sometimes after booting:

[image]

This obviously leads me to believe that there is an update available somewhere, but clicking on it does nothing, and I can't find any updates in the Software Updater either. It would at least help if it let me know how to install them.

How/where do I install these updates, and if this is a bug, how do I fix it?

Comment: If you run `sudo apt dist-upgrade` it should pull any updates and get rid of the message.

Comment: @MarkKirby I just did that. I'll answer my own question if I notice it hasn't come up for a while.

Comment: I have the same "symptom" after upgrading from 15.04 over 15.10 to 16.04. I get the notification several times a day, although there are no updates available and I disabled the update-notifier, cause I use unattended-upgrades. I am not sure what is going on here. Please spare me with sudo apt-get update/upgrade/dist-upgrade, I am no moron.

Comment: This then sounds like a bug, I would advise doing a fresh install first though.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Hey panda, any other advice? Reinstall is not an option for me, since I don't know the bios password of my laptop, its encrypted and Linux Users are made to Windows users, if we talk to the IT-Support about issues. :(

Comment: Please run the Ubuntu Software Center and check out the Updates tab. See if you can install the updates from there.

Comment: See answers to [question 781268](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781268/why-do-i-receive-software-update-notifications-if-there-are-no-updates-available).

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend to clean your packages and run an update by the terminal.
first:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

and than I have a nice code  for you- I ran it since 6 years, started an my 12.04 and now at (still) 16.04 LTS and be very happy with it:

```
sudo apt-get -y update; sudo apt-get -y upgrade; sudo apt-get -y autoremove
```

to explane:

```
 -y:         says "yes" to the question "are you shure you want..." 
 update:     prepares the system packages upgrade 
 upgrade:    does the packages update (no deleting or installing of new packages)
 autoremove: removes packages what are no longer needed
 ;         : compared to && it will do the following command even the first command would not execute completely
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra and outdated notification messages are a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1592382). This has been fixed in development and the update will be released for Ubuntu 16.04 soon, probably later this month (June 2016).

Try running `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`.