# Why do I receive Software Update notifications if there are no updates available?

Tags: updates, 16.04, notification

I keep receiving the following notification about new updates:

[image]

If I then run the Software Updater, however, I don't receive any of these updates on Ubuntu 16.04.

[image]

Does someone have the same problem?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/773874/disable-gnome-softwares-notification-bubble-notify-osd-for-available-updates/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra and outdated notification messages are a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1592382). This has been fixed in development and the update will be released for Ubuntu 16.04 soon, probably later this month (June 2016).

Answer (score 5):

If you run the new 'Ubuntu Software' application (same icon as the old 'Ubuntu Software Centre', i.e. a capital 'A') the you will see the updates. I'm not sure why 'Software Updater' (icon  is a circle with arrows) is out of sync but it is. I asked a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765377/what-updates-is-ubuntu-software-installing?noredirect=1#comment1165581_765377) 
here

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that there is a distro update. Try running `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`. Dist upgrades are different than the usual software upgrades so ubuntu may have a problem with it. 16.04 is still new and they changed their software store.

Comment: Thanks! I receive a total of [50 packages to be upgraded](http://i.imgur.com/fzXCGWg.png). Is this a safe operation?

Comment: Yes , it will upgrade your linux headers, so basically not the softwares but the operating system itself. As 16.04 is a new distro you will get a lot of these upgrades for some time. It is good to check once in a month. They are safe, they are already tested and should not cause any problem. It will probably ask you to reboot when its done.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/369722/